# Como puedo crear archivo .env desde linea de comandos unix

Tags: javascript, nodejs, virtualenv

intento hacer una conexión al puerto 3000 desde la variable de entorno .env
Trato de crear el archivo .env con el comando nano .env desde la ruta de comandos Unix.
,
Le pongo los siguientes parámetros:

```
PORT=3000
APP_SECRET="THIS_IS_TOP_SECRET"
```

pero no me crea nada.

Ahora En index.js
pongo el siguiente código

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

const MY_PORT = process.env.PORT;
const MY_APP_SECRET = process.env.APP_SECRET;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
 return res.send(MY_APP_SECRET);
});

app.listen(MY_PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${MY_PORT}`));
```

Arranco el demonio y me marca el siguiente error:
**Server running on port undefined**

Comment: Y tiene que ser con `nano`?

Comment: No, solo que cree el archivo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente usando `touch` y `echo`:

1. Crea el archivo usando `touch .env`.
2. Añade la primera línea con `echo "PORT=3000" > .env`.
3. Luego agrega la segunda línea con `echo "APP_SECRET="THIS_IS_TOP_SECRET" >> .env`.

> En caso de que no puedas usar `touch`, simplemente empieza desde el punto 2. La diferencia entre `>` y `>>` es que `>` elimina todo el contenido del archivo, y `>>` agrega contenido nuevo al final. Por eso puedes omitir el paso 1.

Otra opción es utilizar `printf`:

1. `printf '%s\n%s\n' 'PORT=3000' 'APP_SECRET="THIS_IS_TOP_SECRET"' >> .env`.

Y pues en general existen muchas formas de crear archivos y agregar contenido a ellos desde línea de comandos, puedes revisar [este enlace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77277/how-to-append-multiple-lines-to-a-file) (en inglés) para consultar otras opciones.

Comment: Gracias amigo, es que no me había fijado que lo tenia oculto, ya con un la -lFa. Me lo mostro

Comment: Al redireccionar la salida de un comando con `>` siempre se crea un archivo nuevo, por lo que `touch` no es necesario. Con `>>` solo se creará si no existe y se redirige la salida del comando al final del archivo.